Point and Teleport problem with XR Interaction Toolkit in Unity 2022.3.17f1
I have a problem with my VR Experience. Basically, I have setted my XR Origin component, with both left hand and right hand with their corrispective model. Both gameobjects have attached the teleportation script to move through raycasting (point and teleport) on the terrainmap. It actually works, and I have no problem in managing the experience a part from one small detail:
What happen is that when I build the environment on my meta quest Pro headset and I start the game, sometimes (JUST SOMETIMES not ALWAYS) either the Left or the Right teleportation controller doesn’t work, the ray is present and visible, but the player doesn't teleport to where he/she pointing. With that I mean that it is possible to point the raycaster, it appears green (as it should) but then the player doesn’t teleport to where he/she pointing and is forced to use the other controller. In this specific case it is important for the user to be able to teleport with both controller since it will be for a research that take into account users’ main hand.
Can you help me telling me what do I have to fix? Or, If it’s a problem not that clear how can I move around it and still forced the controller to work somehow? I would be very greateful if you can help me out thanks.
It is important to state out that I have fixed my application frame at 30fps and that the render scale is 0.8 due to the weight of the project. Draw calls are at the first frame (to load all the informations) at 900 batches but then they lower down to 300 batches for the whole experience. AA is at 2x with MSAA. I'm using Universal Render Pipeline.
P.S. I’m building the environment with Unity 2022.3.17f1
